# Best way to ensure nested object value exists before calling it in Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

For example :

```
data = {info: {name: john}}
```

How can I make sure when doing :

`const name = data.info.name`

That `name` exists, and I won't get : `Can't read value name of undefined`

Right now I'm doing :

```
let name 

if(!!data && data.info && data.info.name){
  name = data.info.name
}
```

But it seems messy, wondering if there's a better way

Comment: can you use lodash?

Comment: Lodash offers [get](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#get)

Answer (score 3):

You don't need an `if` statement, you can assign the expression directly:

```js
const data = {info: {name: 'john'}};
const name = data && data.info && data.info.name
console.log(name);

const data2 = {};
const name2 = data2 && data2.info && data2.info.name;
console.log(name2);
```

You can use [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) with defaults:

```js
const data = {info: {name: 'john'}};

const { info: { name } = {}} = data || {};

console.log(name);

const data2 = undefined;

const { info: { name2 } = {}} = data || {};

console.log(name2);
```

There's also the [TC39 stage 1 proposal - optional chaining](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining), which you can use with a [babel plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining):

```
const data = {info: {name: 'john'}};
// if any part of chain is undefined, name will be undefined
const name = data?.info?.name;
```

Comment: Optional chaining may one day be a nice thing. You should mention it on the marked duplicate. +1